# Unexpected behavior of Windows 11, when creating or renaming a folder, delayed browser response time

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, browser, windows-11

I have an HP gaming 16 laptop with windows 11 home, the hardware is not so bad core i5 of 10th generation, 16 gb of ram and a HDD accompanied by intel optane.

> HDD and Optane is around 95% healt by CrystalDiskInfo

I have performed several times a clean installation from 0 with the Windows 11 Regional ISO, the problem is that from the beginning, even the times that I have restored or reinstalled Windows, it begins to function that I personally consider to be incorrect:

***1. When creating folder or renaming:***

- from a folder using the context menu or ribon, i go to new-> new folder.
- the directory does not appear.
- I press F5 and then the directory appears with the option to change the name.
- I put the name and press enter to finish.
- the directory appears but is still named "new folder
- I press f5 and the directory is renamed to the name I defined above.

Does anyone know if there is a related bug or solution?

***2. Delayed browser response time.***

- When I am browsing normally as a work in development, very soon I have to upload files or download them.
- The problem is that when I go to download something (click on the link that starts the download) a temporary blockage occurs in the browser (2 seconds) which in the long run is noticeable and annoying instead of being fluid.
- The same thing happens when I need to upload a file, when I open the dialog to search for the file and choose the file, when I click accept, the same thing happens, the browser is temporarily blocked.

I don't know if 1 and 2 are related, but it seems that the part of the operating system that has to do with document or directory management has inappropriate behavior.

***Question:***

1. What additional information or evidence do I require to have a starting point towards finding a solution.
2. What should I do to find a solution later?

***Update***

- All drivers are up to date, no devices with yellow mark.
- Bios are up to date.
- Windows update are up to date.

Comment: Your generic ISO might be missing some drivers. Check if in Device Manager some devices have yellow warning triangles. Check for drivers on the websites of the manufacturers of your computer components, and especially for a BIOS update from HP.

Comment: @harrymc All drivers are up to date.

Comment: Including the BIOS? You could check the Event Viewer for useful error messages.

Comment: @harrymc yes, all up to date.

Comment: I would suspect Optane: some of the behavior suggests the Optane cache may not be updating or properly interacting with the GUI. Just a thought as I have never used Optane